# Enable .Net 4 Mono on OpenSuse

Tags: opensuse, apache-httpd, mono, .net

I have an OpenSuse Linux server and want to run an ASP.net web project. I have installed the `apache2` module `mod-mono`, but when I try to access the ASP web pages it looks as if it is attempting to use .Net 2 when the project is built under .Net 4.

How can I change it to use .Net 4?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In mod-mono's configuration file you must set `MonoServerPath` to `mod-mono-server4` as explained [here](http://www.mono-project.com/Mod_mono#Paths).